# My validator receives an observable which is always empty

Tags: angular, rxjs

I created a custom validator for my form. It is supposed to check whether the value entered in a specific input field is not already present in a local array.
As this array is regularly updated but is still empty at creation time (when I create the form and declare validators), I created an `Observable` of the array, to pass as a parameter to the validator. But on the validator side I **never get any value**, even if the array has some.

Can you help me to figure out what I have done wrong please?

```js
values: RowData[] = []; // The values array which is regularly updated
values$: Observable<RowData[]>;

constructor() {
    this.values$ = of(this.values); // Observable of the array

    // Build form
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [
        '',
        checkIdUniqueValidator(this.generalWellsIds$),
      ]
    });
  }
```

Below is the custom validator:

```js
export function checkIdUniqueValidator(existingValues$: Observable<RowData[]>): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    let existingValues: Array<string>;

    // Here I try to get values from the Observable
    const tempSub = existingValues$.subscribe(x => existingValues = x.map(y => y.id));

    const valueAlreadyExists = existingValues 
      && existingValues.length > 0 
      && existingValues.includes(control.value);

    tempSub.unsubscribe();

    return valueAlreadyExists
      ? {duplicate: {value: control.value}}
      : null;
  };
}
```

Comment: Code within subscribe runs after `const valueAlreadyExists =...`. That's the asynchronous nature of observables. You can switch to using AsyncValidator to fix

Comment: Use the AsyncValidator interface : https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-a-custom-async-validator

Comment: I get the idea, but I don't see how to modify the content of the validator... If I keep the same workflow (subscribe then test values) won't I get the same issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AsyncValidator` approach works good in your case. You could turn your validator function into something like this:

```js
export function checkIdUniqueValidator(
  existingValues$: Observable<RowData[]>
): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) =>
    existingValues$.pipe(
      map((rowDataList) => rowDataList.map((rd) => rd.id)),
      map((existingValues) =>
        existingValues.includes(control.value)
          ? { duplicate: { value: control.value } }
          : null
      ),
      first()
    );
}
```

Then in order to use it, you should use the `FormControl` constructor to pass it like this:

```js
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: new FormControl('', {
    validators: [Validators.required],
    asyncValidators: [checkIdUniqueValidator(this.valuesSource$)]
  })
});
```

The `this.valuesSource$` observable should actually be some sort of `Subject` so that you can emit new values, whenever your `values` array changes (when you `push` into it, or remove elements from it).

```js
values: RowData[] = []; // The values array which is regularly updated
valuesSource$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.values);
```

If you leave it like this, it won't be updated. Your observable will only emit the empty array once, and that's it. You'll never have the `ID`s that were already used unless you call `this.valuesSource$.next(this.values);` whenever you modify the `this.values` array.

I simulated the update of the `this.values` array with a timeout and it seems to work as expected.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.values.push({ id: '1' });
    this.values.push({ id: '2' });
    this.values.push({ id: '3' });
    this.valuesSource$.next(this.values);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would have missed the `next` part. I also had to pipe a call to `first()` after the 2 `map`, otherwise the form would remain in "pending" state. Could you edit your answer please as I can accept it as the solution?

Comment: I added the `first()` operator so that the form doesn't stay in `PENDING` state. Thanks for the catch :).